# Refer to ansible inventory ip address

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I got the inventory file with content of ip addresses,

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
```

I want to capture the  ip address especially when it's passing to the tasks and looping it.  If use the variables on ansible facts, I'm afraid I might use other/wrong ip address.

So is it possible to grab the input from the inventory?

Thanks.

Comment: @techraf The `ipv4` address is what's wanted, not the hostname

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23257539/2308683

Comment: @cricket_007 With the host file OP posted in the question, `inventory_hostname` will contain the IP address for each host.　・　And OP explicitly mentioned they **do not want** to rely on facts, so why do you post a link to an answer suggesting exactly that?

Comment: @techraf They said they are afraid facts would be wrong. Which I don't understand that myself. Plus, adding `debug` would show if it's correct or not before applying it